# Set Active Tab in Tab Nav coming from another link Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, tabs

**EDIT** : This is not my Main Navigation Bar, it is a Nav Bar inside a Form. This Tab Nav only exists in `resources-terms.html`

[image]

I have a Tab Navigation located at `resources-terms.html` which is

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab_bar">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>AU and NZ Terms & Conditions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> UK Terms & Conditions </a></li>
   </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"> Content 1</div>
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2"> Content 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's say I am viewing `index.html` what should be the link format that I need to directly go to `resources-terms.html` with the tab2 already selected and active?

I tried `<a href="resources-terms.html#tab2>Link</a>"` but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for (navigating to a particular tab via `location.hash` value) will not happen on it's own. You'll need to handle this in your `resources-terms.html` file.

After the page is completely loaded, read the hash and set the corresponding tab active as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (location.hash) {
        $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: I edit my question,  seems it is confusing as someone might assume that my Tab Nav Bar is my Main Nav Bar, it's not my Main Nav Bar. based on your code how it is supposed to know which tab should it set active? and As for my question, If am coming from index.html what link should I put in to directly go tab 2 as active?